# create a scatterplot with mean and standard error of the mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot, standard-error

I am trying to create a scatterplot using ggplot2. Besides the individual values, I want to display the mean for each group and the standard error of the mean. Below you can find an example of the desired result which I created using GraphPad Prism.

I thank you very much in advance for your precious time!
BR

[image: plot in GraphPad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code replicates your plot fairly well:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = y, group = group)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = group), size = 3,
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.1)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, 
               fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), 
               fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)),
               geom = 'errorbar',  width = 0.25) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = mean, fun.max = mean,
               geom = 'errorbar',  width = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 30)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 15)) +
  labs(x = '', y = '') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Your data needs to be in the following format:

```r
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), times = c(8, 4)),
                 y = c(1.8, 2.5, 2.4, 4, 5.5, 13, 14, 26,
                       2.3, 2.8, 5.5, 10))

df
#>    group    y
#> 1      A  1.8
#> 2      A  2.5
#> 3      A  2.4
#> 4      A  4.0
#> 5      A  5.5
#> 6      A 13.0
#> 7      A 14.0
#> 8      A 26.0
#> 9      B  2.3
#> 10     B  2.8
#> 11     B  5.5
#> 12     B 10.0
```

Comment: What does the 'group=group' in the first aes part specify? In the second one, I understand that it specifies the parameter to choose the shape, but the first? And is there a way to change the order of the Groups on the x axis?

Comment: The `group = group` ensures that the summary functions work on the points in group A and group B separately. You can change the order of the groups on the x axis by making the grouping variable a factor and changing the default (alphabetical) order like this: `df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c('B', 'A'))`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `geom_errorbar()` function in ggplot2. You should be able to reproduce a plot similar to that in figure using `geom_errorbar()` and `geom_dotplot()`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).